# In the SugarCRM ACL Access Roles, what takes priority when more than 1 list set the same permission?

Tags: mysql, acl, sugarcrm

This SQL query for SugarCRM ACL system gets the permissions for each module that are set for a specific **acl access role list**.

The column `aclAccess` and `access_override` set a number value which determines the permission of that module for users who belong to this access control list.

The issue I have is a user can belong to multiple access lists.

Assuming a user belongs to 2 lists which both set a different permission on a module action.

How could I determine which one to apply and use for the user?  Any ideas?

When 2 or more ACL access roles set different module permission values on a module and a user belongs to these roles, which permission takes priority to be used?

---

**Example**

if I belong to ACL access role A and B and A sets lead edit permission to no and B sets it to Yes...would I get the yes or no edit permission for my user?

---

**This SQL will return the permission for a supplied ACL Access List**
So I would run this query on each list a user belongs to to get there permissions.

My issue is when more than 1 of these list set permissions on a module which conflict with each other.  IN that case I do not know which one should be applied to the users ACL permission for viewing the pages.

```
SELECT acl_actions.*
 ,acl_roles_actions.access_override 
 FROM acl_actions 
 LEFT JOIN acl_roles_actions ON acl_roles_actions.role_id = '9eda04a8-a1b7-071b-3f2f-558f5c1aaec0' AND  acl_roles_actions.action_id = acl_actions.id AND acl_roles_actions.deleted = 0
 WHERE acl_actions.deleted=0 
 AND category='apoll_Web_Projects' 
 OR category='apoll_Web_Project_Files' 
 OR category='ProjectGanttChart' 
 ORDER BY acl_actions.category, acl_actions.name
```

[view full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl4DN.png)
[image]

---

**Convert permission number to string value mapping...**

```
 if(!defined('ACL_ALLOW_NONE')){
  define('ACL_ALLOW_ADMIN_DEV', 100);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_ADMIN', 99);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_ALL', 90);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_ENABLED', 89);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_OWNER', 75);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_NORMAL', 1);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_DEFAULT', 0);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_DISABLED', -98);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_NONE', -99);
  define('ACL_ALLOW_DEV', 95);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most restrictive should apply.

> When a user belongs to multiple roles, the more restrictive setting prevails. For example, if a user is assigned to one role that restricts deleting accounts, and the same user is also assigned to a role that permits deleting accounts, the user will not be able to delete accounts because Sugar recognizes the most restrictive aspects of each assigned role. Access permissions for a particular user are displayed on their Sugar Users module record view.

https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Administration/Role_Management/Introduction_to_Roles/#Assigning_Multiple_Roles_to_a_User